# send video via ZMQ pubsub using python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyzmq

I would like to create a simple client/server setup using Python and ZMQ.
The client must send live video from my laptop webcam to the server, which displays the video.

I have come across a few 'answers', but I've not been able to get any of them to work other than when sending images as base64. I do not want to send as base64 - it is slow with a lot of overheads. I think it makes more sense to send the image byte data.

Here is my Client:

```
import base64
import zmq
import time
import cv2
from imutils.video import VideoStream

ctx = zmq.Context()

send_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
send_sock.bind("tcp://*:1235")

vs = VideoStream(src=0, resolution=(640, 480)).start()
time.sleep(2.0)  # allow camera sensor to warm up

while True:  # send images as stream until Ctrl-C

    frame = vs.read()
    encoded, buf = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    image = base64.b64encode(buf)
    send_sock.send(image)

    # detect any kepresses
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

send_sock.close()
ctx.term()
```

And here is my Server:

```
import zmq
import time
import base64
import numpy as np
import cv2

ctx = zmq.Context()

rcv_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
rcv_sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1235")
rcv_sock.subscribe("")

while True:

    image_string = rcv_sock.recv_string()
    raw_image = base64.b64decode(image_string)
    image = np.frombuffer(raw_image, dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(image, 1)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    time.sleep(0.1)

    # detect any kepresses
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break


rcv_sock.close()
ctx.term()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code above, using Base64, does work.

How can I do the same but without Base64 (I'm looking for a faster solution).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply to remove the base64 encoding...

Client:

```
frame = vs.read()
encoded, buf = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
send_sock.send(buf)
```

Server:

```
raw_image = rcv_sock.recv()
image = np.frombuffer(raw_image, dtype=np.uint8)
frame = cv2.imdecode(image, 1)
cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use opencv instead, works in real-time.

**Server:**

```
import zmq
import cv2

ctx = zmq.Context()

send_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
send_sock.bind("tcp://*:1235")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        encoded, buf = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        send_sock.send(buf)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
send_sock.close()
ctx.term()
```

**Client:**

```
import zmq
import time
import base64
import numpy as np
import cv2

ctx = zmq.Context()

rcv_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
rcv_sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1235")
rcv_sock.subscribe("")

while True:
    raw_image = rcv_sock.recv()
    image = np.frombuffer(raw_image, dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(image, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Receiver stream", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

rcv_sock.close()
ctx.term()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```